# Extraer parte de la ruta de un fichero en php?

Tags: php, string

estoy haciendo un proyecto personal en el que se me ha presentado un problema, estoy usando codeigniter 3.6, el caso es que he logrado recorrer de forma recursiva un directorio, del cual extraigo la ruta de los archivos que necesito, pero me devuelve la ruta real de los mismos y quisiera poder eliminar de esas cadenas una parte en específico para poder mostrar los archivos en la web. 
Me explico, con este código:

```
private function glob_recursive($directory, &$directories = array()) {
    foreach(glob($directory, GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT) as $folder) {
        $directories[] = $folder;
        $this->glob_recursive("{$folder}/*", $directories);
    }
}
private function getimages($directory, $extensions = array()){
    $this->glob_recursive($directory, $directories);

    foreach($directories as $directory) {
        foreach($extensions as $extension) {
            foreach(glob("{$directory}/*.{$extension}") as $file) {
                #print_r($files = $file);
                $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
                $allinfo[] = $info->getBasename();

            }

        }

    }
    return @$allinfo;
}
```

Obtengo:

`array(120) { [0]=> string(41) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\02-03-11_1945.jpg" [1]=> string(41) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\02-03-11_2043.jpg" [2]=> string(41) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\06-11-10_1828.jpg" [3]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\100_4235.jpg" [4]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\100_4236.jpg" [5]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\100_4237.jpg" [6]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\100_5641.jpg" [7]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\otras\100_5642.jpg" [8]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\otras\100_5643.jpg" [9]=> string(36) "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\otras\100_5644.jpg"" ...`

y quisiera obtener algo como:

`array(120) { [0]=> string(41) "02-03-11_1945.jpg" [1]=> string(41) "02-03-11_2043.jpg" [2]=> string(41) "06-11-10_1828.jpg" [3]=> string(36) "100_4235.jpg" [4]=> string(36) "100_4236.jpg" [5]=> string(36) "100_4237.jpg" [6]=> string(36) "100_5641.jpg" [7]=> string(36) "/otras/100_5642.jpg" [8]=> string(36) "/otras/100_5643.jpg" [9]=> string(36) "/otras/100_5644.jpg"`

**NOTA: La ruta "E:\Imagenes\carpinteria\" es la carpeta root que le paso a la función para que lea recursivamente su contenido**
Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: Codeigniter no tendrá identificada la ruta absoluta del root en alguna variable global por ahí?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he solucinado el problema gracias por la ayuda, dejo el codigo para quien le sirva, saludos!!

```
    private function glob_recursive($directory, &$directories = array()) {
    foreach(glob($directory, GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT) as $folder) {
        $directories[] = $folder;
        $this->glob_recursive("{$folder}/*", $directories);
    }
}

private function getimages($directory, $extensions = array(), $cat_path){
    $strfind = $directory;
    $base_url = base_url() . $cat_path;
    $this->glob_recursive($directory, $directories);
    foreach($directories as $directory) {
        foreach($extensions as $extension) {
            foreach(glob("{$directory}/*.{$extension}") as $file) {
                $info = new SplFileInfo($file);
                $eval = $info->getPath() . '/' . $info->getBasename();
                $allinfo[] = array(
                    "src"           => str_replace($strfind,$base_url, $eval),
                    "thumb"         => substr(base_url() . 'assets/thumbnails/'. $info->getFilename(), 0,-4) .'_thumb.'.$info->getExtension(),
                    "realpath"      => $eval,
                    "data-caption"  => $info->getFilename(),
                );

            }

        }

    }
    return @$allinfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según leo [por ahí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242972/codeigniter-dynamically-getting-relative-absolute-path-outside-of-application), COdeIgniter tiene disponible la ruta absoluta del controller en `FCPATH`

En el index.php se definen estas variables para usarse a lo largo de la aplicación

```
EXT: La extensión de archivo para los PHP 
FCPATH: Ruta al front controller (this file) (root of CI)
SELF: El nombre del archivo THIS (index.php)
BASEPATH: Ruta al folder system 
APPPATH: Ruta al folder “application”
```

Con esto, en tu código podrías usar algo parecido a

```
$processed_path = str_replace(FCPATH, "", $info->getBasename());
```

(no sé si pueda usarse la variable global directamente, sólo sugiero de acuerdo a lo que recuerdo de PHP. La cosa es que puedes quitar fácilmente la ruta global si ya la tienes... incluso si tienes que hacer otro paso previo para reemplazar `\` por `/` o cosas así)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el caso es que cuando leo la información de la carpeta utilizo la clase splfileinfo de php que trabaja con las rutas reales de los archivos en mi disco duro..... me hago entender?? Saludos y gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Edité la respuesta para indicar cómo puede usarse esa info...

Comment: probando su sugerencia, su respuesta funciona parcialmente, pues elimina toda la ruta del fichero, quedando solo el nombre del mismo, no me ha servido, pero gracias por la dedicacion y el tiempo